# What is different between execute and execute_script selenium function python

Tags: python, selenium

I know execute_script runs js code but what actually execute function do ?

Comment: Example of `execute` function?

Comment: driver.execute('quit')

Comment: I have shared the github link with you, in their they have discuss what exactly the execute() and exceute_script() does, i have not answered anything more because there is so much to say about it and it's better to understand it in your own way https://github.com/ghaering/pysqlite/issues/41 I hope that will help you in case, you need any more help you can comment down below happy to help